# DIagnosing another Windows 7 Lockup

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I'm running Windows 7 on a fairly modern machine (8GB ram, AMD FX-6100, GTX 560ti) and I notice that periodically Windows seems to just hang for a little while. This occurs frequently after a cold boot and I start up five or six small to medium sized programs. It also occasionally occurs during normal usage. Basically what occurs is that the screen locks up and there is no keyboard responsiveness for a period of 30 seconds to a full minute. After a bit of patience, control is returned but I'm interested in figuring out what is causing such lockups. I checked the event log and don't see any issues, and all I can see in Task Manager is a spike in cpu and memory usage right after this occurs.

Any tips on how to even begin to diagnose this?

Comment: Install procmon and let it log everything to file so that when the machine locks up you can check the logs to see what's causing the high resource utilisation. Also try `sfc /scannow` to verify your system files. Check your power settings too.

Comment: We're getting quite a lot of that on Windows 8 as well, especially on some lightweight laptops with SSD speed boosts (not sure if that is an issue) though only for around 1-3 sec not 30. I'd also want to check out the hard drive. Run [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com) if you can to make sure there are no errors.